# CouchDB with Node.js: How to insert HTML document as attachment

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, couchdb

I'm doing some experimentation with the node-couchdb library and I'm trying to insert an HTML document as an attachment into the database. My HTML file is named test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>This is a test</h1>
    </body>
<html>
```

My backend (in express.js) looks like

```
app.use('/insertattachment', (req, res) => {
     couch.insertAttachment(
         'test_database',
         'document_id',
         'test.html',
         'rev_id'
     ).then(({data, headers, status}) => {
          console.log('success');
     }, err => {
          console.log('failed');
     })
})
```

When I sent a http request to the backend, the console printed 'success', but I was unable to locate the attachment anywhere when I logged into the fauxton portal for couchDB.

Any ideas? I am not really familiar with couchDB in general. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, you should be getting an error because of a missing revision id. Suspect you're not running the code you think you're running (or that you've shown).